# PhoneGap PushPlugin Registration ID dont work in movil

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I'll be very grateful who can help me with this
I need to retrieve the regid of each device and server phonegap and serves me right, but when I emulate on a android device, no longer shows the id

the index.js

```
var app = {
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
        document.getElementById("toggleBtn").addEventListener('click', this.toggle, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function() {
      console.log('deviceready event');
       app.push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "143828535864"
            },
            "ios": {},
            "windows": {}
        });

       app.push.on('registration', function(data) {
           console.log("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
           document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
           alert(data.registrationId);
           var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
           var idReg=jQuery("#idReg").val(data.registrationId);


           if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
               // Save new registration ID
               localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
           }
       });
    },
};
 app.initialize();
```

and the config.xml

```
<content src="index.html" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="*" />
    <allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-navigation href="data:*" />
    <allow-intent href="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>
    <platform name="ios">
        <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
        <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
    </platform>
    <!--<plugin name="PushPlugin" value="com.plugin.gcm.PushPlugin" />-->
    <plugin name="phonegap-plugin-push" spec="~1.7.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="0.2.3" />
```

Answer (score 0):

First check the sender ID in Google developers console project and try the following change.

```
app.push = PushNotification.init({
            "android": {
                "senderID": "143828535864"
            }
        });
```

Comment: hi thanks for your answer, and check my account, and that is the sender id, you have any other recommendations that can guide me to the solution